# Splitting a string by list of indices

Tags: python, string, split, indices

I want to split a string by a list of indices, where the split segments begin with one index and end before the next one.

**Example:**

```
s = 'long string that I want to split up'
indices = [0,5,12,17]
parts = [s[index:] for index in indices]
for part in parts:
    print part
```

**This will return:**

> long string that I want to split up
>   string that I want to split up
>   that I want to split up
>   I want to split up

**I'm trying to get:**

> long
>   string
>   that
>   I want to split up

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
s = 'long string that I want to split up'
indices = [0,5,12,17]
parts = [s[i:j] for i,j in zip(indices, indices[1:]+[None])]
```

returns

```
['long ', 'string ', 'that ', 'I want to split up']
```

which you can print using:

```
print '\n'.join(parts)
```

Another possibility (without copying `indices`) would be:

```
s = 'long string that I want to split up'
indices = [0,5,12,17]
indices.append(None)
parts = [s[indices[i]:indices[i+1]] for i in xrange(len(indices)-1)]
```

Comment: Another way is, `[s[i:j] for i,j in izip_longest(indices,indices[1:])]` but I like your way better!

Comment: This copies the indices list with `indices[1:]` and creates a new list with double size by the `zip` function -> Bad performance and memory consumption.

Comment: @ms4py This is fine, performance is not an issue in this case, this is a very readable solution. If performance is an issue my suggestion can be used.

Comment: eumiro- thank you, this works great. Can you explain how the +[None] part works?

Comment: @ms4py - ok, there's an updated version withou copying of the list and without zip. Although your `itertools` version is probably more performant.

Comment: @Yarin - `indices[1:] + [None]` copies the array without the first element and adds a `None` at the end. So for your `indices` it looks like `[5,12,17,None]`. I am using it to be able to access the last part of the string with `s[17:None]` (the same like `s[17:]`, just using two variables I have anyway).

Comment: @Yarin `[1:None]` for example is the same as `[1:]`

Comment: @ms4py What do you mean by that?

Comment: Not sure it's your fortee but how would on do this in NodeJs?

Comment: This had been a hectic for me since an hour and half. Thanks @eumiro

Answer (score 5):

Here is a short solution with heavy usage of the [itertools module](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html). The `tee` function is used to iterate pairwise over the indices. See the *Recipe* section in the module for more help.

```
>>> from itertools import tee, izip_longest
>>> s = 'long string that I want to split up'
>>> indices = [0,5,12,17]
>>> start, end = tee(indices)
>>> next(end)
0
>>> [s[i:j] for i,j in izip_longest(start, end)]
['long ', 'string ', 'that ', 'I want to split up']
```

**Edit**: This is a version that does not copy the indices list, so it should be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the alt approach- ill have to check out itertools sometime

Comment: Neat approach, learned something new. Is there an easy way to get rid of the extra blank at the end of the first 3 strings inside the expression? I tried `s[i:j].strip()` but that didn't work at all (not sure why not)

Comment: If you are gonna use this you may as well use the pairwise function straight from the itertools docs. Also using `next(end)` is preferred to `end.next()` for python 3 compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a generator if you don't want to make any modifications to the list of indices:

```
>>> def split_by_idx(S, list_of_indices):
...     left, right = 0, list_of_indices[0]
...     yield S[left:right]
...     left = right
...     for right in list_of_indices[1:]:
...         yield S[left:right]
...         left = right
...     yield S[left:]
... 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> s = 'long string that I want to split up'
>>> indices = [5,12,17]
>>> [i for i in split_by_idx(s, indices)]
['long ', 'string ', 'that ', 'I want to split up']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (a bit more readable):

```
parts=[]; i2=len(s)  #--> i1 and i2 are 'startIndex' and 'endIndex'

for i1 in reversed(indices): parts.append( s[i1:i2] );  i2=i1

parts.reverse()
```

This **reverses** the indices and therefore **starts splitting from the last index position to the 'endIndex' i2 (which is updated in every loop)**.

Of course the elements are in the wrong order than. That's why I reversed the result array at the end.

I think for beginners this is a bit more readable than the accepted answer.