# Trim Array Element in List Comprehension

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, fixed-width

Adapted code from [Splitting a string by list of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851445/splitting-a-string-by-list-of-indices/10851582#10851582) to load fixed width data into excel sheet but don't understand how to trim the results for each array item in the the last line of the [[List Comprehension]](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) function.

Note - data is not loaded into the excel sheet unless the print line is commented out.

```
from itertools import tee, izip_longest
import openpyxl

def fixed_reader(df, data_start, data_end, indices, ws):
    with open(df, 'rb') as f:
        for line in range(0, data_start): next(f)
        for index, line in enumerate(f):
            if index == data_end: break
            start, end = tee(indices)
            next(end)
            print([line[i:j].rstrip('\r\n') for i,j in izip_longest(start, end)])      # <<<<<
            ws.append([line[i:j].rstrip('\r\n') for i,j in izip_longest(start, end)])  # <<<<<

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
fixed_reader('FixedWidth.dat', 3, 7, [0,1,6,8], ws)
wb.save('FixedWidth.xlsx')
```

**FixedWidth.dat**

```
1C4PJLAB1FW506827
SMT701PD57J348217
1GTEG15X541150523
3GYFNCE39CS56512
1GCGK24N9PE171689
K   U G7FU046394G
1FTEF25NXKNA45683
1G2PF37R8FP298952
JC2UA2127B059 944 5D
JH2PC4080AK380263
1FT7W2BT7FEC79068
```

Comment: Can you provide what the expected output should be for the first line of the `.dat` file?  It's not really clear what you want trimmed.

Comment: ['K', '   U ', 'G7', 'FU046394G'] -> ['K', 'U', 'G7', 'FU046394G']

Comment: So you just want to remove all whitespace from all strings?

Comment: Just trim spaces at each end of each array element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trim whitespace from both ends of each string using `.strip()`, or use `.strip(' ')` to just trim spaces.

```
line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
ws.append([line[i:j].strip(' ') for i,j in izip_longest(start, end)])
```