# Segmentation of a string before a curtain substring

Tags: python, string, split

I want to segment a string into multiple strings before a curtain substring.
Example:

```
string = 'Hello this is a text Hello this is another text Hello this is yet another text'
```

Segment before every 'Hello' so that

```
string_1 = 'Hello this is a text'
string_2 = 'Hello this is another text'
string_3 = 'Hello this is yet another text'
```

Using string.split('Hello') removes the 'Hello's from the strings, which I don't want. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: You might wann check regex and lookaheads specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with the regular expression counterpart of `split()`, `re.split()` (plus some post-processing). The regex `'(?=Hello)'` matches at positions followed by the string `Hello`, without matching the `Hello` itself.

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.split('(?=Hello)', string)
['',
 'Hello this is a text ',
 'Hello this is another text ',
 'Hello this is yet another text']
```

To get exactly your result, you can extend that to `[x.strip() for x in re.split('(?=Hello)', string) if x.strip()]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string = 'Hello this is a text Hello this is another text Hello this is yet another text'
import re
x=[m.start() for m in re.finditer('Hello', string)]
print(string[x[0]:x[0+1]])
j= [string[i:j] for i,j in zip(x, x[1:]+[None])]
print(j)
```

Few lines where referred from:

[Splitting a string by list of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851445/splitting-a-string-by-list-of-indices)

[How to find all occurrences of a substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring)

Output:

```
['Hello this is a text ', 'Hello this is another text ', 'Hello this is yet another text']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex, the following would suffice:

```
string = 'Hello this is a text Hello this is another text Hello this is yet another text'

substr = 'Hello'

result = [substr + s for s in string.split(substr) if s.strip()]

print(result)
```

The result is:

```
['Hello this is a text ', 'Hello this is another text ', 'Hello this is yet another text']
```

Of course, if you want to get rid of the space at the end of each part, you could do instead:

```
result = [(substr + s).strip() for s in string.split(substr) if s.strip()]
```

So that the result will be:

```
['Hello this is a text', 'Hello this is another text', 'Hello this is yet another text']
```